# Google Colab IPython notebook files often fail to be saved

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm getting a terrible trouble with my Deep Learning porjects. My google colab files mostly fail to save. The status shows

> Saving Changes...

However, never succeeds. After a while

> Automatic document saving has been pending for n minutes. Reloading
> may fix the problem. Save and reload the page.

Reloading is not the remedy and after reloading, the problem is not solved. I really don't know what to do with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check disk space or permits, sometimes drive and collab became unstable.

Also check if it can be saved while kernel is free and not busy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are Iranian, I also had this problem and the reason was that the Shecan (شکن) was enable. I disabled the Shecan and it worked!
(or other similar tools!)